# Solve a system of non-linear equations: $2(a-b)=29+4ab$, $2(c-b)= 11+4bc$, $2(c+a) = 9-4ac$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

> So I've solved this system of equations: $$\begin{array}{lcl}2(a-b) & =& 29+4ab \\2(c-b)& = & 11+4bc \\2(c+a) & = & 9-4ac\end{array}$$

by simply solving for each variable in terms of the others, separately and plugging them into the other equations. It does get tedious and I don't want to sit with this for $40$ min in an exam. Is there any efficient way to solve a system like this?

Comment: Is there some tool you are meant to use here?  The method suggested seems reasonable.  You can't solve by inspection, as the solutions are not so nice: $(-3,3.5,-1.5)$ and $(2,-2.5,0.5)$.

Comment: No not really anything special, I was just seeking some kind of algebraic trick or something to simplify the arithmetic.

Comment: Please see if you can find a better title for this post that avoids too much $\LaTeX$. Regards,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's $$(2a+1)(2c+1)=10,$$ $$(2b-1)(2c+1)=-12$$ and $$(2a+1)(2b-1)=-30.$$

The rest is smooth:
$$(2a+1)^2(2c+1)^2(2b-1)^2=3600,$$
which gives
$$(2a+1)(2c+1)(2b-1)=60$$ or $$(2a+1)(2c+1)(2b-1)=-60.$$ 
If $(2a+1)(2c+1)(2b-1)=60$ then we obtain:

$2a+1=\frac{60}{-12}$, $2c+1=\frac{60}{-30}$ and $2b-1=\frac{60}{10}$, which is
$a=-3$, $b=\frac{7}{2}$, $c=-\frac{3}{2}$.

If $(2a+1)(2c+1)(2b-1)=-60$ then the work is similar

and we get the answer:
$$\left\{\left(-3,\frac{7}{2},-\frac{3}{2}\right),\left(2,-\frac{5}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)\right\}$$

Comment: How do you simplify the first lines?

Comment: @Parseval From third equation. $4ac+2a+2c+1=10$.

Comment: Damn, it's so simple when you point it out. How does one just "see" these things? One more question, how is it trivial that the product of those 3 squares sives you the solutions? If I squareroot both sides I get $$(2a+1)(2c+1)(2b-1)=60.$$

Comment: @Parseval I saw before that $(x+1)(y+1)=xy+x+y+1$ and in your problem there are similar things. $(2a+1)(2c+1)(2b-1)=60$ or $(2a+1)(2c+1)(2b-1)=-60$. If $(2a+1)(2c+1)(2b-1)=60$ then we obtain: $2a+1=\frac{60}{-12}$, $2c+1=\frac{60}{-30}$ and $2b-1=\frac{60}{10}$,

Comment: How do you go from $(2a+1)(2c+1)(2b-1)=60$ to $2a+1=-\frac{60}{12}$? I get $2a+1=\frac{60}{(2c+1)(2b-1)}.$

Comment: @Parseval $(2c+1)(2b-1)=-12$.

Comment: Yes, thanks man!

Comment: @Parseval You are welcome!

Answer (score 7):

Shouldn't take that long, even by brute force. From the 1st equation:

$$
(4a+2)b = 2a - 29 \;\;\iff\;\; b = \frac{2a-29}{4a+2}
$$

From the 3rd equation:

$$
(4a+2)c = 9 - 2a \;\;\iff\;\; c = \frac{9-2a}{4a+2}
$$

Substitute the above into the 2nd equation, and you get a nice quadratic in $a$ with real solutions.